# BeautifulSoup class find returning None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python program, using BeautifulSoup, that will retrieve a download link on a website. I am using the find method to retrieve the html class that the link is located in, but it is returning None.

I have tried using accessing this class using parent classes, but was unsuccessful.

Here is my code

```
link = 'https://data.worldbank.org/topic/agriculture-and-rural-development?view=chart'

for link in indicator_links:
    indicator_page = requests.get(link)
    indicator_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    download = indicator_soup.find(class_="btn-item download")
```

Again, I want the download link located inside the `btn-item download` html class.

Comment: What is `indicator_links`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link it will be 100% in a < a > tag.
This is the best I can do to give a helping hand:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

page_url = "https://data.worldbank.org/topic/agriculture-and-rural-development?view=chart"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(page_url), 'lxml')

what_you_want = soup.find('a', clas_="btn-item download")
```

This should give you the link you want.

Not sure what you are trying to do in your code since I can't tell what indicator_links is.

Comment: Invalid Syntax to start with.

Comment: Where exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean all links inside the `btn-item download` html class?

Change your code with this one:

```
link = 'https://data.worldbank.org/topic/agriculture-and-rural-development?view=chart'

page = requests.get(link)
indicator_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
download = indicator_soup.find(class_="btn-item download")
for lnk in download.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(lnk['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was creating the BeautifulSoup object with the wrong html argument. 
It should have been:

```
indicator_soup = BeautifulSoup(indicator_page.text, 'html.parser')
```

instead of

```
indicator_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```